# CoffeeScript Refactoring shared variable

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm new to CoffeeScript and trying to understand how to refactor this example.  Since both functions share canvas and context is there a way to pull them out side the functions and share them instead of repeating myself?  I'm sure it is something obvious I'm missing, but I have not been able to get it to work.

CoffeeScript File

```
@draw_rectangle = ->
  canvas = document.getElementById("main_canvas")
  context = canvas.getContext("2d")
  context.fillRect(50, 25, 150, 100)

@draw_square = ->
  canvas = document.getElementById("main_canvas")
  context = canvas.getContext("2d")
  context.fillRect(100, 50, 100, 50)
```

HTML Body:

```
<body>
  <canvas id="main_canvas"></canvas>
  <p><a onclick="draw_square()" href="#">Draw Square</a></p>
  <p><a onclick="draw_rectangle()" href="#">Draw Rectangle</a></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the most elegant way would be to use a class, or at least an object, that would hold both methods and the `canvas` and `context` variables. The object would also keep track of whether it's been initialized already. Here's a first attempt:

```
painter =
  draw_rectangle: ->
    @init() unless @initialized
    @context.fillRect 50, 25, 150, 100

  draw_square: ->
    @init() unless @initialized
    @context.fillRect 100, 50, 100, 50

  init: ->
    canvas = document.getElementById "main_canvas"
    @context = canvas.getContext "2d"
    @initialized = true
```

Now, if you later decided that you wanted to have multiple canvases, it'd be very easy to change `painter =` to `class Painter` and reuse the code.

Comment: Your solution is exactly what I'm looking for, but clicking on the links is no longer drawing the rectagle/square.  I should be calling painter.draw_rectangle() instead of draw_rectangle() in the onclick attribute, correct?

Comment: missing : after property id
  I'm seeing this javascript error in the firebug console, and clicking the links is still no longer working.

Comment: Well, it should really be `@painter =` or `window.painter =` to make it a global... does that fix the issue?

Comment: Sorry to keep bugging you but the problem is still present.

Comment: You *are* compiling the code to JavaScript, right? What line number does Firebug attribute the error to?

Comment: Yep, I'm compiling to javascript.  On page refresh, line 3 of the javascript gives an error "missing : after property id
 shapes.js
Line 3".

Comment: Ugh, sorry, my bad. I was putting `@` on the method names, which is nonsense. `this.foo: bar` doesn't make any sense (except in a `class`, where it's an acceptable alias for `this.foo = bar`).

Comment: I added an @ to painter to resolve a painter undefined error.  I'm now getting a this.context is undefined for line 13 of the js (the return context line of rectangle/square)

Comment: There was another boo-boo in my code: I had `@init` rather than `@init()`. Sigh. Please try it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom helper method to draw a rectangle.

```
canvasRectangle = (id, x, y, w, h) ->
  canvas  = document.getElementById(id)
  context = canvas.getContext("2d")
  context.fillRect(x, y, w, h)

@draw_rectangle = ->
  canvasRectangle("main_canvas", 50, 25, 150, 100)

@draw_square = ->
  canvasRectangle("main_canvas", 100, 50, 100, 50)
```

Comment: That does fix the repetition nicely, though I think the questioner wanted to avoid running the `document.getElementById` and `canvas.getContext` functions repeatedly. If you were drawing a lot of rectangles and squares, that'd probably get to be a performance drag.